# Confusing puzzle in probability

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, conditional-probability

I have this question which is confusing me. I searched a lot to find an explanation but without success, though I am sure that it is a known puzzle and there is someone who asked it before!

We know that, with probability $p$, the person we are looking for lives in a certain $7$-story building. If this person lives in the building, then he is equally likely to live on any of the $7$ floors.

- What is the probability that he lives on the $7$th floor of this building?
- We explore without success the first $6$ floors. What is the probability now that he lives on the $7$th level?

How to solve this question? Do we need to assume that the probability is equally-likely? Do we take into consideration that the person lives outside the building?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know

I. $P(\text{In building})=p$

II. $P(\text{Floor 7} | \text{In building})=\dfrac{1}{7}$

For question 1, you are looking for:

$P(\text{Floor 7}) = P(\text{Floor 7} | \text{In building})P(\text{In building})+P(\text{Floor 7} | \overline{\text{In building}})P(\overline{\text{In building}})$

For question $2$ you are finding the same thing, but given the information "the person is not on floors 1 through 6", you know that $P(\text{Floor 7} | \text{In building}) = 1$

Comment: I see... thanks

Comment: but hasn't the probability that (s)he lives in the building also changed from the given information?    Why not  P(Lives on 7 | not lives on 1-6)  = P[( L on 7) and (not L on 1-6)] / P (not L 1-6) = P (lives on 7) / P (not live 1-6) = ... = p / (7-6p)

Comment: For question 1 no. The answer is $p/7$. For question 2, yes, the answer is $p$ since $P(\text{Floor 7} | \text{In Building and not on 1-6})=1$

Comment: @DavidPeterson You considered that the second question asks to find the probability $p("Floor~~7")$ while the user Ned didn't understand the same

Comment: @Ned Why you think the second question asks to find the probability  =  P(Lives on 7 | not lives on 1-6)  why not it asks to find $P(Lives~ on ~7 )$ ? which intuition led you to this? really I am lost now!

Comment: I guess the word "now" in the second question -- you are given that he's not on floors 1-6, then "now what is the probability that he's on floor 7 is, to me, the conditional probability that he's on 7 given that he's not on 1-6. And I got  $ (p/7)/(1-6p/7) = p/(7-6p)$ since (unconditional) prob. that he's on 1-6 is $6p/7$.

Comment: Look, suppose $p=1/2$, so 1/2 the time he's not in the building and 1/14 of the time he's on any one particular floor. Given that he's not on floors 1-6, then the prob. that he's on floor 7, given not on 1-6, is $(1/14) / (1/14 + 1/2) = 1/8$. I stick with my answer, it's standard  conditional probability. Do you really think that after finding he's not on 1-6, that you'd make a 50/50 bet that he's on floor 7?

Comment: Again, the problem is in English so maybe you can claim there's ambiguity in the wording, but you are saying that with p= 1/2, you think there is 50/50 chance he is on floor 7 after you find out that he's not on 1-6. Do you actually believe that? Think about it!

Comment: Last attempt to convince you: shuffle a 14 card deck which contains one Ace and split into two seven card piles, one called "building" which laid out in a row of 7 face down, and the other pile is "not building". There is 50/50 chance the Ace is in the "building" pile. Now turn over cards 1-6 in the "building" pile and it turns out the Ace is not among them. What is the probability that Ace is 7th card in "building" pile? Do you think it's 50/50?